# Clipping List Selector

Tags: android, listview

Lets say I have a ListView/GridView with each row consisting of an ImageView. In addition, each row has some padding to it. Ideally in this case, we would want the list selector to be on top so we use `drawSelectorOnTop="true"`. Ok, no problem, except the list selector covers the entire area of the row. Ideally, I would like to have the list selector cover only the area of the ImageView. Below is an example of what I am talking about.

The left is what ideally should happen, and the right is what actually happens.

[image]

The only solution I could come up with is to add an extra "empty" View on top of the ImageView that matches in height/width and use that empty View as the selector. I'm wondering if there are any other or better ways to accomplish this?

Comment: How about customising the listselector to be a drawable shape with the right padding?

Comment: @KenWolf Hmm, I've only thought about using 9 patches, but using a shape drawable never crossed my mind. I'll look into it, this may end up being a great solution.

Comment: put an inset-drawable in your selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `InsetDrawable` as your custom selector with a custom `ShapeDrawable`

For example:

`drawable/my_selector.xml`

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/my_shape_drawable" 
    android:insetBottom="10dp"
    android:insetLeft="10dp" 
    android:insetRight="10dp" 
    android:insetTop="10dp"/>
```

`drawable/my_shape_drawable.xml`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/selector" />
</shape>
```

This assumes your `ImageViews` are all of uniform size.

Comment: The InsetDrawable works great. Although, I have a header view which needs to be the same width as the screen. This might be a stretch, but any way to use remove the inset from the header row?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure to be honest. Another option might be to NOT use the grid/list-view selector, but just change selector states in the individual child views, if you know what I mean. Then you can just set a different background/state_pressed for your header view.

Answer (score 3):

use layer-list drawable.

drawable/selector_drawable.xml

`<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ><item
        android:drawable="@drawable/internet_list_focused_holo_light"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:right="10dp" 
        android:left="10dp">
    </item>
</layer-list>`